# ASP.NET MVC Identity and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, ldap, asp.net-identity, identity

I am looking to integrate ASP.NET Identity and Active Directory Identity in a single MVC Solution.

This solution will be deployed in 2 different server. When the internal users access the URL it should validate against LDAP and redirect appropriately.

When the URL is accessed in a external site it should validate against SQL auth and redirect appropriately.

Is this achievable in ASP.NET MVC using IDENTITY? Appreciate your response.

Comment: Couldn't you just have one site where the user logs in and check against LDAP and then SQL if the LDAP fails authentication?

Comment: @Shoe Any chance you can point me to an article that would show what that looks like? That's exactly what I think I need for a site I'm writing where we'll have external users tracked with Identity, and internal users that I need to auth against [on premises] AD.

Comment: @ScottK.Fraley See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888006/how-to-use-windows-active-directory-authentication-and-identity-based-claims/28891029#28891029

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some customization in you code.

Have a flag (isLDAPUser) in your Users Table and based on that flag validate against the Password accordingly.