# How to use Windows Active Directory Authentication and Identity Based Claims?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

### Problem

We want to use Windows Active Directory to authenticate a user into the application. However, we do not want to use Active Directory groups to manage authorization of controllers/views.

As far as I know, there is not an easy way to marry AD and identity based claims.

### Goals

- Authenticate users with local Active Directory
- Use Identity framework to manage claims

### Attempts (Fails)

- Windows.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory - Doh. This is for Azure AD. No LDAP support. Could they have called it AzureActiveDirectory instead?
- Windows Authentication - This is okay with NTLM or Keberos authentication. The problems start with: i) tokens and claims are all managed by AD and I can't figure out how to use identity claims with it.
- LDAP - But these seems to be forcing me to manually do forms authentication in order to use identity claims? Surely there must be an easier way?

Any help would be more than appreciated. I have been stuck on this problem quite a long time and would appreciate outside input on the matter.

Comment: Can you use active directory federated services (ADFS)? If so, it can expose a claims aware authentication point that the windows security model natively understands. After the authentication, you can implement a custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager to fill in the additional custom claims that your application needs. If you can't use ADFS, ThinkTecture has a identity server that is open source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shoe your solution above pushed me toward a direction that worked for me on MVC6-Beta3 Identityframework7-Beta3 EntityFramework7-Beta3:

```cs
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // Check for user existance in Identity Framework
    //
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.eID);
    if (applicationUser == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username");
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // Authenticate user credentials against Active Directory
    //
    bool isAuthenticated = await Authentication.ValidateCredentialsAsync(
        _applicationSettings.Options.DomainController, 
        _applicationSettings.Options.DomainControllerSslPort, 
        model.eID, model.Password);
    if (isAuthenticated == false)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // Signing the user step 1.
    //
    IdentityResult identityResult 
        = await _userManager.CreateAsync(
            applicationUser, 
            cancellationToken: Context.RequestAborted);

    if(identityResult != IdentityResult.Success)
    {
        foreach (IdentityError error in identityResult.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // Signing the user step 2.
    //
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(applicationUser,
        isPersistent: false,
        authenticationMethod:null,
        cancellationToken: Context.RequestAborted);

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Is `Authentication` an MVC6-only feature? It's not clear where that is supposed to come from and it's kind of a critical piece.

Comment: I believe the "Authentication" is supposed to represent whatever class or domain context that is used to verify the username and password against the domain controller. Such as in the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement -> PrincpalContext().ValidateCredentials(username, password)

Answer (score 22):

Just hit AD with the username and password instead of authenticating against your DB

```cs
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if (user != null && AuthenticateAD(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

public bool AuthenticateAD(string username, string password)
{
    using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN"))
    {
        return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I am curious about with this approach. Have you been able to use identity based claims in the application? I want to authenticate with AD, but authorize with identity based claims.

Comment: `SignInAsync` (from the template) is setting up the identity stuff which includes the claims. All `AuthenticateAD` is doing is checking the user/pass against AD.

Comment: I assume this requires a login page and thus allows us to hit the Login as a post?

Comment: Yeah, if you generated your project from a template all you would need to do is add the `AuthenticateAD` function and modify the login action.

Comment: I'm getting an error for SignInAsync. I am using something like SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, authenticationMethod: "active directory", cancellationToken: Context.RequetAborted). It gives me a null exception for claims?

Comment: Take out authenticationMethod and cancellationToken. All you need is what is above in my answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have a link to documentation on what the parameters mean for SignInAsync? I want to understand why I don't need them. Also, PrincipalContext() is mysterious to me. Did you define this yourself or is it a helper method in a library I am obviously unaware of? Thanks for your replies Shoe.

Comment: Oh another thing. You code would not work for me unless I stated: SignInManager.SignInAsync. I cannot invoke the method without SignInManager. :-)

Comment: `SignInAsync` used to be a helper method before SignInManager existed. The concept is the same, though. `PrincipalContext` comes from namespace `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Add a reference to that in your project to use it.

Comment: Yeah, what throws me off is I wonder if PrincipalContext exists in ASP.NET5 somewhere? I'm trying to bring System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in through the project.json as CTP6 just can't auto resolve that reference by just droppoing. I tried. Joys of beta. :)

Comment: No, it doesn't because it's a namespace dedicated to working with Active Directory, thus not related to ASP.NET

Comment: Okay, duh. I'm almost there. I just cannot get it to resolve in the VS15 CTP6 project. How did you get this to resolve Shoe? Otherwise, I probably will have to write the LDAP authentication method manually.

Comment: Resolve in what way? Should just be in the .NET framework assemblies by default. Right click "References" -> Add Reference -> search for "directory"

Comment: @Shoe great solution, however is there an alternative to make this work is developing for both DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0? It seems like anything related to ASP.NET Core is Azure AD related only.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Not sure, unfortunately I probably won't get to know until the official release of asp.net 5. When that happens I'll be sure to update this answer.

Answer (score 5):

On ASPNET5 (beta6), the idea is to use CookieAuthentication and Identity : you'll need to add in your Startup class :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
        .AddUserStore<MyUserStore<MyUser>>()
        .AddRoleStore<MyRoleStore<MyRole>>()
        .AddUserManager<MyUserManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

In the configure section, add:

```cs
private void ConfigureAuth(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity & Cookie authentication
    app.UseIdentity();
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/App/Login");
    });
}
```

Then, you will need to implement:

```cs
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRoleStore
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory
```

and extend/override:

```cs
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SignInManager
```

I actually have setup a sample project to show how this can be done.
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/jesblit/ASPNET5-FormAuthenticationLDAP).

I tested on the beta8 and and with some small adaptatons (like Context => HttpContext) it worked too.

Comment: Hi hlyates, did this post answer your question?

Comment: Does this approach still work for RC1? I gave you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the approve! Yes this also works with RC1, there are however some naming changes to apply (for example Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel becomes Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel).

Comment: Looks like major changes are looming with it ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 down the pike?

Comment: Yes! It changes too often now and RC was supposed to be stable, but they still make core changes... I'll wait untill RC2 is final before I make changes on my side.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ClaimTransformation, I just got it working this afternoon using the article and code below.  I am accessing an application with Window Authentication and then adding claims based on permissions stored in a SQL Database.  This is a good article that should help you.

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/863

In summary ...

```
services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformer, ClaimsTransformer>();

app.UseClaimsTransformation(async (context) =>
{
IClaimsTransformer transformer = context.Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IClaimsTransformer>();
return await transformer.TransformAsync(context);
});

public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;

        public ClaimsTransformer(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _context = dbContext;
        }
        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
        {

            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = null;

            foreach (var i in context.Principal.Identities)
            {
                //windows token
                if (i.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity))
                {
                    windowsIdentity = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)i;
                }
            }

            if (windowsIdentity != null)
            {
                //find user in database by username
                var username = windowsIdentity.Name.Remove(0, 6);
                var appUser = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == username);

                if (appUser != null)
                {

                    ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Id", Convert.ToString(appUser.Id)));

                    /*//add all claims from security profile
                    foreach (var p in appUser.Id)
                    {
                        ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(p.Permission, "true"));
                    }*/

                }

            }
            return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to design a solution to this problem this way:

```
1. Any AD authenticated user will be able to access the application.
2. The roles and claims of the users are stored in the Identity database of the application.
3. An admin user will be able to assign roles to users (I have added this functionality to the app as well).
```

Read on if you want to see my complete solution. The link to the full source code is towards the end of this answer.

### Basic design

```
1. User enters Active Directory credentials (Windows login credentials in this case).
2. The app checks if it's a valid login against AD.
    2.1. If it's not valid, app returns the page with 'Invalid login attempt' error message.
    2.2. If it's valid, go to next step.
3. Check if the user exists in the Identity database.
    3.1. If Not, create this user in our Identity database.
    3.2 If Yes, go to next step.
4. SignIn the user (using AD credentials). This is where we override UserManager.
```

**Note:** The user created in step 3.1 has no roles assigned.
An admin user (with valid AD username) is created during Db initialization. Adjust the `Admin2UserName` with your AD username if you want to be the admin user who will assign roles to newly added users. Don't even worry about the password, it can be anything because the actual authentication will happen through AD not through what's in Identity database.

[image]

### Solution

**Step 1:**
Ensure that you've got Identity setup in your application. As an example, I'm taking a Blazor Server app here. If you don't have Identity setup, follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-blazor-server-project) from Microsoft learn.

Use [my project](https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/AddADAuthentication) to follow along the guide.

**Step 2:**
Add `ADHelper` static class to help with Active Directory login. In my example, it's at *Areas/Identity/ADHelper.cs* and has contents that look like this:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace HMT.Web.Server.Areas.Identity
{
    public static class ADHelper
    {
        public static bool ADLogin(string userName, string password)
        {
            using PrincipalContext principalContext = new(ContextType.Domain);
            bool isValidLogin = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName.ToUpper(), password);

            return isValidLogin;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**
Override `CheckPasswordAsync` method in `UserManager` so you can authenticate users against Active Directory. I have done this in *Areas/Identity/ADUserManager.cs*, the contents of which look like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace HMT.Web.Server.Areas.Identity
{
    public class ADUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser> where TUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ADUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators,
            IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger)
            : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer,
                  errors, services, logger)
        {
        }

        public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(TUser user, string password)
        {
            var adLoginResult = ADHelper.ADLogin(user.UserName, password);
            return Task.FromResult(adLoginResult);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4:**
Register it in your `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services
.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
})
.AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
.AddUserManager<CustomUserManager<ApplicationUser>>()  <----- THIS GUY
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

`ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationRole` and `ApplicationDbContext` look like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**
Update `OnPostAsync` method in *Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml.cs* to implement the authentication flow. The method looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Step 1: Authenticate an user against AD
        // If YES: Go to next step
        // If NO: Terminate the process
        var adLoginResult = ADHelper.ADLogin(Input.UserName, Input.Password);
        if (!adLoginResult)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }

        // Step 2: Check if the user exists in our Identity Db
        // If YES: Proceed to SignIn the user
        // If NO: Either terminate the process OR create this user in our Identity Db and THEN proceed to SignIn the user
        // I'm going with OR scenario this time
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.UserName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            var identityResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = Input.UserName,
            }, Input.Password);

            if (identityResult != IdentityResult.Success)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user was authenticated against AD successfully, but failed to be inserted into Application's Identity database.");
                foreach (IdentityError error in identityResult.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }

                return Page();
            }
        }

        // Step 3: SignIn the user using AD credentials
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

### Basically, we're done here.

**Step 6:**
Now if an admin user wants to assign roles to newly added users, simply go to Manage Users page and assign appropriate roles.
[image]
Pretty easy, right? 
[image]

**Step 7:**
If you want to manage roles (add, edit, delete), simply go to *manage/roles* page.
[image]

### Conclusion

This setup ensures that users are authenticated using Active Directory and are authorized using roles in the Identity database.

### Complete source code

https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/AddADAuthentication

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to implement a custom `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider`? You should be able to use this (override `ValidateUser`) in conjunction with `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials()` to authenticate against active directory.

try:

`var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "example.com", "DC=example,DC=com");
pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If possible, could you please confirm that this suggestion is for ASP.NET5?

Comment: No, I didn't realize you were asking about that specifically. I've never tried it on ASP.NET 5 and IDK if Directory Services is in .NET core, but you could use full .NET if need be.