# How to authenticate to Blazor (to use authorize view) if I already authenticated through active directory?

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a class that I authenticate with Active Directory and it returns true or false whether or not a user is authenticated. How do I add this user to now be known as authenticated and use the AuthorizeViews in Blazor server? I have been doing some research online but am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: It's too huge a topic to post an answer here.  You would need to stitch together two concepts: 1) authenticate with AD, and 2) build custom authentication.  Here are some links for these concepts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553897/10787774, https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/authentication-in-blazor-webassembly/